# Query to convert the count to million or thousands

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

I am running a query on a database to return count(*) for number of rows.

- If the count is greater than million say 2,250,304, I want the query to return 2.25M.
- If the count is greater than 1000 but less than a million say 65130 I want the query to return '65.1k'.
- If the count is less than 1000 then the query should return actual count.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DATENAME(mm, CREATEDTS) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy, CREATEDTS) AS Month,
       CASE
         WHEN count(*) > 1000
              AND count(*) < 1000000 THEN ( CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), ( count(*) / 1000 )) ) + 'k'
         WHEN count(*) > 1000000 THEN ( CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), ( count(*) / 1000 )) ) + 'm'
         ELSE COUNT(*)
       END
FROM   USAGEDATA
GROUP  BY month(CREATEDTS),
          DATENAME(mm, CREATEDTS) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy, CREATEDTS)
ORDER  BY MONTH(CREATEDTS)
```

When I run it I am getting an error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value '165k' to data type int.

I am not sure where I am converting varchar to INT and getting this error.

Comment: Presumably the second `/1000 ` should be dividing by a million. Also `1000000` falls through to the else in error.

Answer (score 7):

This type of formatting is generally best done in your application if possible.

The problem is that the [case expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) returns a result based on the highest [datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) of any branch.

So you would need to cast the final `COUNT` branch of your `CASE` to `VARCHAR` too as `int` has higher precedence than `varchar`.

Also you should probably add year into your order by except if you actually want to order Jan 2014 and Jan 2015 together followed by Feb and so on.

Though I might well be minded to take that concatenated string out of the `GROUP BY` too and rewrite it (Along the way fixing a couple of other issues with integer division and inconsistent boundary conditions) as.

```
WITH T(mmmyyyy, FORMATTED_COUNT, Yr, Mnth)
     AS (SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, MIN(CREATEDTS)) + ', ' + DATENAME(YEAR, MIN(CREATEDTS)) AS Month,
                CASE
                  WHEN COUNT(*) BETWEEN 1000 AND 999999
                    THEN ( CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), ( CAST(ROUND(COUNT(*) / 1000.0, 1) AS NUMERIC(4, 1)) )) ) + 'k'
                  WHEN COUNT(*) >= 1000000
                    THEN ( CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), ( CAST(ROUND(COUNT(*) / 1000000.0, 2) AS NUMERIC(6, 2)) )) ) + 'm'
                  ELSE CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), COUNT(*))
                END,
                YEAR(CREATEDTS),
                MONTH(CREATEDTS)
         FROM   USAGEDATA
         GROUP  BY YEAR(CREATEDTS),
                   MONTH(CREATEDTS))
SELECT mmmyyyy,
       FORMATTED_COUNT
FROM   T
ORDER  BY Yr,
          Mnth;
```